# How can I find a value which is common in all the database table?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database

I'm working on a project where I've to show notification on a webpage of those sites for which data entry has been done. The data entry is being saved under different database tables with the primary key called "Site ID".

How can I find only those site IDs which are present in all the tables?

Please help, I'm not at all good in SQL quires, your help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you want to use ASP.NET or SQL statement ? And what do you tried ?

Comment: I've no clue how can I make it possible. I thought of doing it using for loop. since our page is very huge I don't want to make it very heavy. Now I'm looking for SQL statement which will be load friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you have few tables in your database then, you can write a Stored Procedure to Select SiteName and SiteID or the columns that you require by doing the INNER JOIN upon all the tables with your unique field SiteID.

For example you could do something like this:

```
Select S.SiteName,S.SiteID from 
Sites S
Inner JOIN AnotherTable AT ON S.SiteID=AT.SiteID
Inner JOIN AnotherTable2 AT2 ON S.SiteID=AT2.SiteID
.............
```

But you need to inner join all of your tables in your query. Inner Join will give you the results for matching records only.
So in this query, SiteName and SiteID will be selected from Sites table only if it matches with all the tables specified below.
I think that will help.

Comment: Ok after inner joining how will I get all the site ids which are common in all the tables?

Comment: As shown in above example, the result you get will be the siteID and SiteName from Sites table with object S, as i mentioned S.SiteName and S.SiteID that matches up with all the tables you mentioned under inner join. It will only pick up those which exists in all the tables you mention.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `INNER JOIN` with all tables with the `Where` filter.

```
DECALRE @valueToSearch VARCHAR(10) = 'BIH004'
Select site .SiteName,site .SiteID 
from 
    Sites site Inner JOIN Table1 t1
        ON site.SiteID = t1.SiteID
    Inner JOIN Table2 t2 ON site.SiteID = t2.SiteID
    .....
WHERE 
     site.SiteID = @valueToSearch
```

But if there are lots of tables then you can try out the following query.

```
DECLARE @SearchStr VARCHAR(10)= '100000'
CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630)) -- Table to hold the results

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
            AND TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'SiteID')-- This is optional if your column name is same trough out all tables
    )
    --This is optional if your column name is same trough out all tables then you can remove the loop and directly use the insert query.
    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL) -- You can avoid this loop if the column name is uniq through out all tables as `SiteID`
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END 
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
```

This will give you the result as,

```
  schema.tablename.columname   valueofthatcolumn
```

Comment: Hi, I've only 5 tables to check in. As you mention in the inner loop section (1st solution). the @valuetosearch is an int value. But in my case the id is a string it looks something like this "BIH004".

Comment: If you are creating stored procedure just make it `VARCHAR(10)`. Here 10 being the max value your parameter can have if you rvalue is more that 10 characters you can increase it as you need or smaller then decrease it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find table where site_Id exist then you can write query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'site_Id'
```